# '[Required]'on property 'Name' causing ModelState to return invalid every time. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I couldn't understand why objects weren't being created at all. So, I used `var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);` to help me figure out what was wrong with my code. It was creating two `Name` instances.
Turns out it was the keyword `[Required]`. I commented it out and the app worked just fine.

Now, I just need to understand why it could be happening. Anyone?

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(Book bookObj)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _db.Book.AddAsync(Book);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }

<div class=" border container" style="padding:30px;">
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class=" col-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Name"></label>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6">
            <input asp-for="Book.Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class=" col-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Author"></label>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6">
            <input asp-for="Book.Author" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class=" col-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.ISBN"></label>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6">
            <input asp-for="Book.ISBN" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-group row">
        <div class=" col-3 offset-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-3">
            <a asp-page="Index" class=" btn btn-success form-control">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share the cshtml code?

Comment: @Sajid Sure done.

Comment: Did you fill Name field and it was not null or empty?

Comment: @Hostel Nope, it was correctly reading strings. What happened was there was a second field Name for some reason.

Comment: I still don't get it when you said there was a second field name. Could you post pictures of this second field Name please?

Comment: @Marlonchosky [Sure](https://i.imgur.com/LpgPmGM.png)

Comment: Try removing the `Book.` prefix. I'm making a wild guess here and assume that if the model is of type `Book` then supplying `Book.Name` to the taghelper, will actually be translated as `Book.Book.Name`.

Comment: Try @Dennis1679's comment, delete the Book. prefix in Razor. That worked?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. This is weird.

Comment: Could you check the generated HTML when you use Required? So we can see if its creating two instances only if you use Required, or every time.

Comment: @Nih.ilus did you use the ``PageModel`` in .netCore for this project? if yes i fond the issue. i don't see in your code `[BindProperty] public Book Book { get; set; }`, but if already exist, you should just delete ``Book bookObj`` from method ``OnPost`` parameter. and will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change like below:

```
[BindProperty]
public Book Book { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost([Bind(Prefix = "Book")]Book bookObj)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't reopened that project in a while. Now it's giving me back this weird 'The application is in break mode.' - when I get past this, I'll test your code. Thank you!